# Webpack 5 splitChunks breaks WebpackDevServer

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-splitchunks

I started with a fresh copy of the create-react-app. I then ran eject, and wanted to add code splitting. However, whenever I add

```
splitChunks: {
        automaticNameDelimiter: '.',
        chunks: 'all',
      },
```

The app is stuck on Starting the development server...

If I remove `chunks: all` The app starts working again.

**Note: I didn't change anything else at all.**

1. npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
2. cd my-app
3. npm run eject
4. edit webpack.config.js
5. npm start
6. Stuck on Starting Development Server....

I don't get any errors or anything useful on how to figure out what the problem is. It's just stuck, any ideas on what could be wrong or what I could do to get more debug info on where things are getting stuck?

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === "development";
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === "production";

  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes("--profile");

  const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));

  const shouldUseReactRefresh = env.raw.FAST_REFRESH;

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve("style-loader"),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith(".")
          ? { publicPath: "../../" }
          : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            ident: "postcss",
            config: false,
            plugins: !useTailwind
              ? [
                  "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
                  [
                    "postcss-preset-env",
                    {
                      autoprefixer: {
                        flexbox: "no-2009",
                      },
                      stage: 3,
                    },
                  ],
                  "postcss-normalize",
                ]
              : [
                  "tailwindcss",
                  "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
                  [
                    "postcss-preset-env",
                    {
                      autoprefixer: {
                        flexbox: "no-2009",
                      },
                      stage: 3,
                    },
                  ],
                ],
          },
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve("resolve-url-loader"),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
            root: paths.appSrc,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    target: ["browserslist"],
    mode: isEnvProduction ? "production" : isEnvDevelopment && "development",
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? "source-map"
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && "cheap-module-source-map",
    entry: paths.appIndexJs,
    output: {
      // The build folder.
      path: paths.appBuild,
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js"
        : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/bundle.js",
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js"
        : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
      assetModuleFilename: "static/media/[name].[hash][ext]",
      publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? (info) =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, "/")
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          ((info) =>
            path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")),
    },
    cache: {
      type: "filesystem",
      version: createEnvironmentHash(env.raw),
      cacheDirectory: paths.appWebpackCache,
      store: "pack",
      buildDependencies: {
        defaultWebpack: ["webpack/lib/"],
        config: [__filename],
        tsconfig: [paths.appTsConfig, paths.appJsConfig].filter((f) =>
          fs.existsSync(f)
        ),
      },
    },
    infrastructureLogging: {
      level: "none",
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {
              ecma: 8,
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,
              comparisons: false,
              inline: 2,
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
            },
            // Added for profiling in devtools
            keep_classnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            keep_fnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
        }),
        new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
      ],
      splitChunks: {
        automaticNameDelimiter: ".",
        chunks: "all",
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: ["node_modules", paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map((ext) => `.${ext}`)
        .filter((ext) => useTypeScript || !ext.includes("ts")),
      alias: {

        "react-native": "react-native-web",
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          "react-dom$": "react-dom/profiling",
          "scheduler/tracing": "scheduler/tracing-profiling",
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [
          paths.appPackageJson,
          reactRefreshRuntimeEntry,
          reactRefreshWebpackPluginRuntimeEntry,
          babelRuntimeEntry,
          babelRuntimeEntryHelpers,
          babelRuntimeRegenerator,
        ]),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Handle node_modules packages that contain sourcemaps
        shouldUseSourceMap && {
          enforce: "pre",
          exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|css)$/,
          loader: require.resolve("source-map-loader"),
        },
        {
          oneOf: [
            {
              test: [/\.avif$/],
              type: "asset",
              mimetype: "image/avif",
              parser: {
                dataUrlCondition: {
                  maxSize: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              type: "asset",
              parser: {
                dataUrlCondition: {
                  maxSize: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              test: /\.svg$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: require.resolve("@svgr/webpack"),
                  options: {
                    prettier: false,
                    svgo: false,
                    svgoConfig: {
                      plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
                    },
                    titleProp: true,
                    ref: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
                  options: {
                    name: "static/media/[name].[hash].[ext]",
                  },
                },
              ],
              issuer: {
                and: [/\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|md|mdx)$/],
              },
            },
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  "babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides"
                ),
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app"),
                    {
                      runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? "automatic" : "classic",
                    },
                  ],
                ],

                plugins: [
                  isEnvDevelopment &&
                    shouldUseReactRefresh &&
                    require.resolve("react-refresh/babel"),
                ].filter(Boolean),
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app/dependencies"),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: false,
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                modules: {
                  mode: "icss",
                },
              }),
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                modules: {
                  mode: "local",
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              }),
            },
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    mode: "icss",
                  },
                },
                "sass-loader"
              ),
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    mode: "local",
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                "sass-loader"
              ),
            },
            {
              exclude: [/^$/, /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              type: "asset/resource",
            },
          ],
        },
      ].filter(Boolean),
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),
      isEnvProduction &&
        shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
        new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime-.+[.]js/]),
      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),

      new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),

      isEnvDevelopment &&
        shouldUseReactRefresh &&
        new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin({
          overlay: false,
        }),
      isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
      isEnvProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
          chunkFilename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css",
        }),
      new WebpackManifestPlugin({
        fileName: "asset-manifest.json",
        publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
        generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
          const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
            manifest[file.name] = file.path;
            return manifest;
          }, seed);
          const entrypointFiles = entrypoints.main.filter(
            (fileName) => !fileName.endsWith(".map")
          );

          return {
            files: manifestFiles,
            entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
          };
        },
      }),
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
        contextRegExp: /moment$/,
      }),
      isEnvProduction &&
        fs.existsSync(swSrc) &&
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest({
          swSrc,
          dontCacheBustURLsMatching: /\.[0-9a-f]{8}\./,
          exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/, /LICENSE/],
          maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
        }),
      // TypeScript type checking
      useTypeScript &&
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
          async: isEnvDevelopment,
          typescript: {
            typescriptPath: resolve.sync("typescript", {
              basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
            }),
            configOverwrite: {
              compilerOptions: {
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                skipLibCheck: true,
                inlineSourceMap: false,
                declarationMap: false,
                noEmit: true,
                incremental: true,
                tsBuildInfoFile: paths.appTsBuildInfoFile,
              },
            },
            context: paths.appPath,
            diagnosticOptions: {
              syntactic: true,
            },
            mode: "write-references",
            // profile: true,
          },
          issue: {
            include: [
              { file: "../**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}" },
              { file: "**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}" },
            ],
            exclude: [
              { file: "**/src/**/__tests__/**" },
              { file: "**/src/**/?(*.){spec|test}.*" },
              { file: "**/src/setupProxy.*" },
              { file: "**/src/setupTests.*" },
            ],
          },
          logger: {
            infrastructure: "silent",
          },
        }),
      !disableESLintPlugin &&
        new ESLintPlugin({
          // Plugin options
          extensions: ["js", "mjs", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
          formatter: require.resolve("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter"),
          eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint"),
          failOnError: !(isEnvDevelopment && emitErrorsAsWarnings),
          context: paths.appSrc,
          cache: true,
          cacheLocation: path.resolve(
            paths.appNodeModules,
            ".cache/.eslintcache"
          ),
          // ESLint class options
          cwd: paths.appPath,
          resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
          baseConfig: {
            extends: [require.resolve("eslint-config-react-app/base")],
            rules: {
              ...(!hasJsxRuntime && {
                "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "error",
              }),
            },
          },
        }),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    performance: false,
  };
};
```

Comment: Hi @Amir, were you able to figure out a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.
It used to work out of the box before, when react-app used webpack@4. Now with webpack@5 they removed this `splitChunks` part from their config. Maybe they ran into same issue.

I don't know how to fix it with webpack@5, but downgrading to previous version of react-app is enough for me. Just add explicit dependency of `react-scripts@4.0.3`.

Comment: Webpack 5 still allows you to edit chunk behavior via `optimization.splitChunks` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationsplitchunks

Comment: @AdamBohannon but it hangs forever in development mode if you set `splitChunks: 'all'`.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11763

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem after ejecting the cra-project.
After inspecting the code of the `start.js`-script, that is used to build and start the dev-server, i found out that it is also using the `webpack.config.js`. So i figured out, that webpackDevServer probably doesn't work with splitChunks, although i don't exactly know why. I also don't need chunk-splitting in my dev-server so i came up with the following solution in `webpack.config.js`:

```
splitChunks: isEnvProduction
  ? {
    automaticNameDelimiter: '.',
    chunks: 'all',
  } : {},
```

What this code does, is only adding the splitChunk-config when in the production-environment. `isEnvProduction` is already used in other places in `webpack.config.js`

I hope this helps anyone stumbling over this question, like i did.

Comment: With this workaround, when you are in dev mode, does it still lazy load the files? With split chunk, I could also tests lazy loaded components in dev mode to make sure it all works as expected.

Comment: @amir i am pretty sure that you won't be able to test this behavior. With the above workaround you basically just do not split chunks in dev mode at all. So all you get is one big bundle.js file containing all your JS-code. This is most definitely not an optimal solution, but a workaround to get the local server running after ejecting a CRA-app. The way to go is probably creating your own webpack-config and build process.